# Visual Studio Code and GIT on the MAC OS

Tags: git, macos, visual-studio-code

Git not detected in the Visual Studio Code on Mac OS.
I see only "There are no active suppliers of management systems", please help.

Enter to bash: git --version, and see "git version 2.18.0", add to $PATH="/usr/local/git/bin".

I looked VSCode in Windows 8 with a Git all good and work. I noticed the difference, in User settings, there are GIT in the extensions, but on the MACOS there are not.

Comment: Did you install Git?

Comment: Yes, Git install with Xcode.

Comment: Delete VSC and setup, all work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to launch vscode from a session where git --version works, meaning your $PATH does reference Git.

If not, check the vscode setting "`git.path`": you can reference directly the executable `git` (`/full/path/to/bin/git`) there.

Comment: Command in the bash: "giti --version" - >git version 2.15.2 (Apple Git-101.1)
Command in the bash: "which git" -> /usr/bin/git
Command in the bash: $PATH - > /usr/bin/git:/Users/konstantin/go/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/opt/X11/bin:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/

Comment: Then try the git.path setting, directly within VSCode.

Comment: In Visual studio code setup "USER SETTINGS" "git.enabled":true,
    "git.path": "/usr/bin/git",

Comment: VSCode write error about "git.path": "Unknown configuration setting".

Comment: and i don't see GIT in the "DEFAULT USER SETTINGS".

Comment: Can you make sure you have the plug-in gitlens installed?